# Recargar UI de una aplicación WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Tengo una aplicación en WPF c# y, tengo 2 ResourceDictionary en el app.xaml. La intención es que a través de un botón se pueda elegir un estilo u otro cargando cualquiera de los 2 archivos.

Esto es lo que hay en el primero:

```
    <ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="estiloTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="estiloCheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDarkCheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,0,0"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

y en el 2do:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="estiloTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="estiloCheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDarkCheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Como se nota las propiedades cambian, y a través de un evento los cargo y funciona, aquí el código del evento:

```
public void OnClick_EventoBarra(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        var ResourceDictionaryEstilos = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("/App;component/estilos/estilos.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        };
        var ResourceDictionaryFuenteChica = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("/App;component/estilos/fuenteChica.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        };

        switch (btn.Name)
        {
            case "btnNormal":
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(ResourceDictionaryFuenteChica);
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(ResourceDictionaryEstilos);
                break;
            case "btnReducida":
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(ResourceDictionaryEstilos);
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(ResourceDictionaryFuenteChica);
                break;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
        Close();
}
```

Esto funciona pero, no se recarga en automático, cuando cambio de pestañas al ser la primera vez que se carga aplica los cambios. Como puedo recargar la aplicación completa para que actualice los estilos de los componentes?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un método de extensión que refresque un control o toda la UI así:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };
    public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
    {
        uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
    } 
}
```

Luego lo aplicas a tu botón una vez le asignas el estilo deseado:

```
btn.Refresh();
```

Espero te ayude.

Luego

Comment: Ya intenté esa solución, pero no funcionó, no se recargó el estilo de la GUI. Lo que quiero es que se repinte el estilo de la ventana, como un "setBackground = rojo" pero que se aplique al cargar los archivos xaml de estilos, como cuando cambias los archivos css.